# what do you call the small changing room in front of the bathroom?

Tags: word-request

So I have this small changing room (4m²) in front of my bathroom that is closed with a sliding door.

Im trying to find out a word to describe it for decoration purposes.

I tried my best searching online.

Comment: I'd probably call it the ***antechamber*** or ***anteroom***. Particularly if *in practice* it often ended up being a "waiting room" for people queuing up to use the lavatory! There's also ***vestibule***, but that has fairly strong "churchy" associations for me.

Comment: Do you mean: That in order to enter you bathroom, you have to go through this changing room? Or, is it to one side of the door to the bathroom?

Comment: May I know what what websites you searched?

Answer (score 5):

I would call it a [dressing room](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dressing-room) *a room for use in getting dressed, especially one for performers backstage in a theater, television studio, etc.*. I have also seen it referred to as a "dressing area" in a home, especially if it doesn't have a door to separate it from the rest of a room.

A "changing room" has an association with a public place like a gym or swimming pool and I wouldn't use it for a home. Dressing rooms typically have a closet, a mirror and sometimes a place to sit. The name is more about the function of the room than its location by the bathroom.

Here is a floor plan that show this usage - although dressing rooms usually tend to be large, the term can also be used for smaller rooms.

> [image: Floor plan showing a "master dressing" room by the master bath]

[An article in Home & Garden](https://www.homesandgardens.com/spaces/decorating/dressing-room-ideas-219188) about dressing rooms shows a small dressing room between a bedroom and a bathroom:

[image: Photograph of a small dressing room from the article]

Comment: Your example with it being located between the bathroom and bedroom is telling. I would expect at least one entrance to the dressing room to come from the bedroom so occupants do not have to go out into the rest of the house naked to get dressed.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, but dressing rooms can also just be attached to master bedrooms and not necessarily near a bathroom. I can't think of an instance where they wouldn't be attached to a bedroom in a home.

Comment: *Dressing room* is perfectly fine and idiomatic.

Comment: I can’t see the dressing room in the picture.

Comment: @我的不好 It is the red room between the open pocket doors. The white rectangles on the left side of the openings are handles for the sliding doors.

Comment: @我的不好 If you click on the photo, it should show you a larger more detailed image now.

Comment: @ColleenV,yes it does I am able to see the dressing room now

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, such a room isn't particularly common. Some large houses have a "dressing room", but these are normally very large, containing wardrobes, and not usually connected to the bathroom.

You could say "changing room", which is what we call communal rooms for changing at gyms, swimming pools etc. It isn't common to have one in a house, but if you stated that you did then it would be understood.

If it is particularly small, just big enough for one person to stand and change in, maybe the word "*cubicle*", or specifically "*changing cubicle*" might best convey the meaning? This is what we call the individual, private rooms within a larger changing room. I believe that in American English they might use the word "stall" in place of "cubicle".

Comment: I came across this in my search for references though: [7 Small Dressing Room Ideas Every Stylish UK Home Owner Would Love](https://contemporarylogliving.com/small-dressing-room-ideas/)

Comment: It's also possible to refer to it as a *closet*, in a generic, although not common, sense. As in the [particular sense of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closet): "**3** : a place of retreat or privacy." In this case, it would be a place of privacy for changing … But I personally would just say *changing room* as already used in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Changing room inside a sports hall
> A changing room, locker room, dressing room (usually in a sports, theater or staff context) or changeroom (regional use) is a room or area designated for changing one's clothes. Changing rooms are provided in a semi-public situation to enable people to change clothes with varying degrees of privacy.
> Separate changing rooms may be provided for men and women, or there may be a non-gender-specific open space with individual cubicles or stalls,[1] as with unisex public toilets. Many changing rooms include toilets, sinks and showers. Sometimes a changing room exists as a small portion of a restroom/washroom. For example, the men's and women's washrooms in Toronto's Dundas Square (which includes a water play area) each include a change area which is a blank counter space at the end of a row of sinks. In this case, the facility is primarily a washroom, and its use as a changing room is minimal, since only a small percentage of users change into bathing suits. Sometimes a person may change his or her clothes in a toilet cubicle of a washroom.
> Larger changing rooms are usually found at public beaches, or other bathing areas, where most of the space is for changing, and minimal washroom space is included. Beach-style changing rooms are often large open rooms with benches against the walls. Some do not have a roof, providing just the barrier necessary to prevent people outside from seeing in.

That was from Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changing_room
That is the link.
Basically,I think it is just while you change your clothes .For some privacy,there should be a  door.